# Factoring a number in Java using loops

Tags: java, joptionpane, factoring

I need to write a program that finds the factors of a number. If it's prime, I just need to say it's prime, otherwise I need to show the factors. I also need to make it so if it's one or the other, it will display a certain statement. I can figure out the decomposing but I can't figure out how to write a display if the number is prime. This must be done using JOptionPane and I'm extremely confused.

Current code:

```
{
    String intro = "Hello!\nThis program will ask you to enter a number and will then tell you whether or not it is prime.\n"
            + "If the number is prime, it will be shown and you will be told it is prime.\n"
            + "If the number is not prime, it willl be shown followed by it's prime decomposition.\n\n"
            + "For example, for 41: The number 41 is prime\n"
            + "For example, for 105: The number 105 will be shown, followed by 3 X 5 X 7";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, intro, "Prime Decomposer, Introduction",1);

    String numPrompt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter any positive integer.\n"
                    + "The number must be positive, and CANNOT be a decimal value such as 1.5\n\n"
                    + "For example, if you wanted to enter the number 12,"
                    + " you would enter: 12", "Prime Decomposer, Integer Entry",1);
    int userNum = Integer.parseInt(numPrompt);
    int iteration = 0;
    int factoredNum = userNum;
    String decomposition = "";
    for(iteration = 2; iteration <= userNum; iteration++)
        {
            while(factoredNum % iteration == 0)
            {
                decomposition += iteration + " ";
                factoredNum /= iteration;
            }

        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number "+userNum+" is not prime. Its decomposition is "+decomposition);
}
```

Comment: *I'm extremely confused.* - What are you confused about?

Comment: What do you think "decomposition" would look like if the number was prime and how could you test the value of "decomposition"?

Comment: @shmosel, I'm confused about how to go about setting up another JOptionPane that will say something like "This number is prime" if it can't be factored beyond itself and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of ugly but I think this will work.

```
int isPrime = 0;    
for(iteration = 2; iteration <= userNum; iteration++)
    {
        while(factoredNum % iteration == 0)
        {
            if(iteration<userNum){
                isPrime++;
            }
            decomposition += iteration + " ";
            factoredNum /= iteration;
        }

    }
    if(isPrime==0){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number "+userNum+" is prime. Its decomposition is "+decomposition);
    }else{
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number "+userNum+" is not prime. Its decomposition is "+decomposition);
    }
```

Comment: Only thing is that we haven't covered booleans and I don't want to risk using it before the lecture. Is there a different way I can set up my while loops where I wouldn't have to use a boolean?

Comment: I mean a boolean is just a primitive data type. If youre using JOptionPanes and `int` and `String` i don't think youll have a problem. Give me a few minutes and ill see if i can think of another way

Comment: I've edited my code and I think it will work. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It works backwards, so if I would put in 105, it says it is prime, when it's not a prime number. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: If needed, I could use boolean, I was just wanting to see if there was an alternate way first.

Comment: Change the line `if(isPrime>0)` to `if(isPrime==0)` that will fix it

Comment: No problem glad I could help. If this is the correct answer please accept it by hitting the green check next to the answer. Happy Coding!